# Logrotate not working with "daily"

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, logrotate, log-rotation

Below is my logrotate configuration.I was not able to get the logrotate work using

"sudo /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf".But if I execute "sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf" it is creating the log file as expected.

```
/var/log/test/test.log {
    daily
    dateext
    dateformat .%Y-%m-%d
    rotate 4
    copytruncate
    compress
    compressext .tar.gz
    missingok
    notifempty
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue?.i am using Ubuntu14.04 operating system.

Comment: Did you check this http://serverfault.com/questions/388066/logrotate-not-working I think you'd get the answer there.